# Get results based upon one relationship in join table

Tags: mysql

I have a join table with two columns of IDs (both joined to other table) and need to filter results to show the list from one column based upon a match of both based upon the page content. Just going around in circles on this...so any help greatly appreciated.

If artistID = 37 and exhibitionID = 234 and  in the table and the page is using GET for the exhibitionID, I need to retrieve all the unique records from exhibitionID (using the title from the exhibition table) with the same result in artistID, ie. 37.

Very simple structure literally two cols, it is drawing on the current page ID that is causing the issu, matching the artistID to the current exhibition ID if that makes sense.

Simply, show a list of all the exhibitions that the artist in the exhibition currently shown appears in. Thank you.

Comment: If you could provide table structure it would make it a lot easier to provide an answer.

Comment: The bit about if the page is using GET is not something mysql can know.  That would need to be handled by your controlling code.